# when do we draw association?

Tags: class, uml, associations

Class Engine has "start(c:Component)" method. So do we need to draw an association between Engine and Component Class IF there is no "new Component()" inside Engine class.

Comment: I've cleaned up the tags a bit...the tags relating to your particular problem domain (engine, component) probably don't help. Also, it seems you're talking about UML class diagrams, so I added that.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not in general need to have an association to a type even if the type is mentioned in a parameter. It entirely depends on if the *state* of an Engine maintains a relationship with one or more Components.

If the Component you passed around is only use locally in method `start`, then there is no real association that persists from one state (one method call) to the next.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an association, it´s a dependency relationship between the two. A dependency means that if the dependee (the Component in your case) changes the depender (the Engine) may become affected (maybe Engine::start was using a Component method that it is no longer available or that has changed its parameters)